# Why need to sleep(1) to allow socket to drain?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I downloaded the source code for a simple static web server from
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/sidefile1.html

However, I'm confused by line 130:

```
#ifdef LINUX
sleep(1);       /* to allow socket to drain */    
#endif

exit(1);
```

Since there is no close for the socket, does it mean I need to wait the client close the socket?

Comment: There's too much code to read, in what context is the sleep used? Usually it's not so, you shouldn't be sleeping but reading the socket until the connection closes or EOF.

Comment: Programs need to sleep too.

Comment: That server is a joke - don't use it in anger, don't study it.  The `sleep` is superstition: unreliable code failed first on Linux so they did something and tried again and it happened to work.  Also: "`ret =read(fd,buffer,BUFSIZE);`   /* read Web request in one go */" - actually needs `recv(..., MSG_WAITALL)`, as `read` may legitimately return with a partial message because the client's allowed to write the request over however many packets it likes (that might even be necessitated by momentary buffering considerations), and packets may be split (or recombined) by network hardware in between.

Comment: @codenheim: universal portability of TCP code is a bit over-ambitious anyway, but in many cases signal handling will be set with `SA_RESTART` or similar (after all, how much code checks e.g. `read` or `write` to file for partial success after a signal? - virtual none, so restarting is usually needed for a system to be reliable though unfortunately it's not on by default when calling `sigaction`).  And on *any* error from `recv` it's often reasonable to close the connection.

Comment: @TonyD: _"on any error from recv it's often reasonable to close the connection"_ -- one of the best lines I've seen in weeks on this site :-)

Comment: @Damon: well - if it's the any/often thing that's amused you, on Linux for example I'd happily say "always reasonable" given the discussion was about `recv(..., MSG_WAITALL)` for on a non blocking socket, and assuming signal handlers are using SA_RESTART (often the only practical choice), as the potential errors are basically that you've lost the connection anyway or your program's got serious errors (providing pointers to inaccessible memory, invalid file descriptors etc).  But, I can't speak to every socket-related function called `recv` on every OS....

Comment: @TonyD: It's not so much amusing me, but I really find it a genuinely good statement. Neglegting `EINTR`, if you got an error from receiving, what useful thing is there left to do anyway, and what do you really care what happened. Either the other side refused the connection (first receive failing with `ECONNREFUSE`), or you have a serious program error, such as using a bad descriptor or a memory allocation issue. In either way, there's not much of a way you can continue in a meaningful way. So your statement is a really good one.

Comment: Hi @Damon - Historically the correct thing to do was to handle EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK and EINTR. Under load, stuff happens. The canonical approach was to spin on `recv` and handle `EINTR` and `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`, even with non-blocking sockets or `select()`. This was true for Linux, as well as other UNIXen. Nowadays, the guarantees are different, but for the decades, if you shipped network software, you learned to code around these things. I see indication that at least one cause of recv returning EAGAIN (after polling indicates ready) is now fixed. It is still a good, defensive practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the author's intent, it is **needless** and **incorrect**. `exit()` is sufficient. When `close()` is called on a TCP socket, or `exit()` is called to terminate the process, unless `SO_LINGER` socket option has been set to a non-default setting, the kernel will keep the socket(s) in a wait state and attempt to deliver any undelivered / buffered data. You can see this with netstat, and is the reason that fast restarting a TCP server that isn't written for fast restart will have a problem reopening the port quickly (there is a proper way to accomplish this too).

I disagree with a couple of things in the accepted answer.

`close()` and `exit()` should have the same effect on the socket, traditionally it has only been a matter of style whether to `close` sockets if you were about to `exit`.

It should have nothing to do with overflowing a TCP send buffer, since it happens after all the writes. Full write buffer will return an error immediately by the `write()` return code; sleeping at the end will be irrelevant to that.

`sleep(1)` should have no effect on the socket buffer or reliable data delivery. If anything, this code throttles the web server child processes after the writes, so really has no good effect, and could actually increase the potential of a denial of service attack.

I am describing default operation. The defaults can be changed via the many options.

For the "bible" on socket programming, see W. Richard Steven's *UNIX Network Programming - Networking APIs: Sockets and XTI* where he covers this in detail.

Comment: I am reading the book,but most of the functions are pre-wrapped. I found some problems doing a independent try and that's why I found this piece of code because all are implemented in raw API.Maybe I haven't gone deeply to the book,but I'll try it.

Comment: "fast restarting a TCP server that isn't written properly will have a problem reopening the port quickly (there is a proper way to accomplish this too)." - it's not a case of written properly vs. not written properly, it's a choice between a fast restart AND a tiny risk of confusing packets for the old server with those for the new, or a slow but totally safe restart.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bit of sloppy code to me.

If a process with an open socket terminates, and the socket has some unwritten data, the kernel is going to tear down the socket without flushing out the unsent data.

When you write something to a socket, the written data will not necessarily be transmitted immediately. The kernel maintains a small buffer that collects the data being written to a socket. Or a pipe, too. It's more efficient to have the process go on, and then the kernel will take care of actually transmitting the written data, when it has time to do that.

A process can obviously write data to a socket much faster than it can be transmitted over a typical network interface, and the size of the internal socket buffer is limited, so if the process keeps writing data to the socket, at some point it will fill up the internal buffer, and will have to wait until the kernel actually transmits the data, and removes the written data from the internal buffer, before there's room to write more.

[*] I am omitting some technical details, such as that the data isn't considered written until the receiver ACKs it.

Anyway, the intent of that `sleep`() call appears to be to allow some time for the internal buffer to actually be transmitted, before the process terminates, because if it does before the actual data gets written, the kernel won't bother sending it and terminate the socket, as I just mentioned.

This is a bad example. This is not the right way to do these kinds of things. The socket should simply be `close`()d. This will correctly flush things out and make sure that everything goes where it's supposed to go. I can't see any valid reason why that example simply didn't properly close the socket, instead of engaging in this kind of hackery.

Comment: You mean write is just write to the buffer,and really sending work is done by kernel,and close will flush the buffer? Another small question,will close send FIN and implement TIME_WAIT?

Comment: The reason I disagree here is that the sleep() is called after all write() calls are complete. It will have no effect on send buffers. Secondly, TCP sockets, by default, are reliable streams. The kernel will hold the stream and deliver unsent data for a period of time, unless you disable this feature. exit() does not circumvent the reliable transmission. It just causes the kernel to automatically close all sockets in the process, and perform the same semantics as `close()` on each stream.